# Draw imageView when touch moved – objective-c

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa-touch

I want the user to draw a UIImageView by movings his finger on the screen. When the user moves finger to the right the width changes etc. This is my code:

This in the drawrect method:

```
if (touchmoved)
{
rectImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, (movePoint.x-startPoint.x), (movePoint.y-startPoint.y))];
rectImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rectImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
rectImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[self addSubview:rectImage];
touchmoved = NO;
}
```

Here the touchmoved is set to YES in the touchedMoved method:

```
if ((movePoint.x > startPoint.x)&&(movePoint.y >startPoint.y))  //startPoint in the locationinView point in the touchesBegan.
{
    touchBegan = YES;
}
```

When I run it on the simulator and move my finger, this is what I get:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: But when I use a CGRect instead of imageview it works perfectly. I need a imageview to access its layer

Comment: Do you remove the previous rectImage from its superview? It looks like you're creating a new view in each `drawRect`...

Comment: yes that could be the case, since every time the touch moves the rectImage is initialised as in the code in the question. But I don't want to remvoe the old one and create a new one, I just want its size to be changed every time. How can I do this?

Comment: ah, obviosly. I solved it by removing it in the touchesMoved method. thanks!!

Comment: A much better way, then, is to store `rectImage` as an instance variable of your view, and then only change its properties instead of allocating a new `UIImageView` every time (which is an expensive operation). You can set the frame via `rectImage.frame`.

Comment: @StatusReport yes but I only want the rectImage to be initialised when the touch mpved, where could I init it then?

Comment: You can define a @property in the class definition, and on touch do something like `if (!self.rectImage) { // initialize... } // Set properties related to touch after rectImage is initialized`.